# Do Overpower level 8 characters get Overpower level 8 weapons from side missions?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just reached level 72 in *Borderlands 2* playing UVHM. I have not done the side quests that give red text and other great guns until now so that I could get max level weapons. However, I was wondering: Should I finish Overpower level 8 as well before doing them or not?

Do OP8 characters get OP8 guns from side missions or do they still give level 72 guns only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the rewards will be OP8 guns/shields/grenade mods if you've accepted quests at OP8.

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/1697175413669456789/)

Comment: oh boy. i waited to reach lvl 72 to get those quests. seems like i have to wait a lot more since reaching op8 is no joke

Comment: @VipinVerma Haha. But if some of the gears are crucial to your build, I would recommend taking it anyway at op1 or whatever you'd like, since quests are easy to reset, if you don't mind re-running main quests. If you just want to collection them... well, have fun in your journey.

Comment: what, how can i reset the quest. i did not know anything about that. so if i want a quest specific item after quest is complete i can get it? how do i reset quest?

Comment: @VipinVerma As I said, you cannot reset specific quest, but you can reset whole quest including main quests - aka, NG+. Here's old question that explains this: [Is there any way to acquire unique guns twice after you've entered Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289898/is-there-any-way-to-acquire-unique-guns-twice-after-youve-entered-ultimate-vaul)

Comment: that's a bummer. to play everything all over again for a single gun. not gonna do it :/

Comment: Is it possible to reset only dlc instead of whole playthrough

Comment: @VipinVerma No, you cannot reset specific DLC or main quest. You can only reset whole playthrough.